# Neo4j 2.2.0 community trying to start shell

Tags: neo4j

When I run Neo4JShell.bat I get
C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin>Neo4jShell.bat
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neo4j.shell.StartClient

Java installed as
C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

Any thoughts?

Comment: tried                                                                                                       C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community>jre\bin\java -cp bin\neo4j-desktop-2.2.0.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient -path "C:\Users\Kevi
n\Documents\Neo4j\scales"
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Neo4j\scales

Comment: installed on linux VM and that works fine - would like it to work in Windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run the Neo4j Community executable.  In the dialog that appears, select "Options", then "Command Prompt".  That sets up your environment.  Then run the shell with "Neo4jShell".

Answer (score 1):

Try the following it should work (let me know if it does not):

1. "Start" the Neo4j Community Server
2. On the same window which was used for step "1.", click on "Options" button.
3. A new Window opens. Click on the button "Command Prompt"
4. A command prompt  window opens up, type "Neo4jShell" or "Neo4jShell.bat" (both works equally fine). This would take you to the Neo4j shell!!

Sincerely,
Nawazish